# Bootstrap datetimepicker widget how to allow invalid mysql dates like '0000-00-00'?

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My Php-Mysql application needs to allow and set some invalid dates in the UI like the mysql default date, 0000-00-00.

When I tried to do this in bootstrap DateTime widget it does seems to remove the 0000-00-00 and becomes empty field. My Code is as below

```
//do the dates now
$("#date").datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
        previous: "fa fa-chevron-left",
        next: "fa fa-chevron-right",
        today: "fa fa-screenshot",
        clear: "fa fa-trash",
        close: "fa fa-remove"
    }
});
```

How do I add/allow options to allow users to enter an invalid date like '0000-00-00'?

Answer (score 1):

Actually its pretty much easy to allow 0000-00-00 as your input date if that's what you want.
There is an option provided by bootstrap datepicker which is **forceParse: *false***

Setting this option to false does all the magic for you which is by default true BUT be alert it comes with great price ;) :)

```
Type: Boolean
Default: true

Whether or not to force parsing of the input value when the picker is closed. That is, when an invalid date is left in the input field by the user, the picker will forcibly parse that value, and set the input’s value to the new, valid date, conforming to the given format.
```

Set this option to ***false*** to allow any wrong dates you want to input

Source: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#forceparse